# Displaying multiple markers that have the same lat/long coordinates in a single popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Leaflet JS - Is it possible query?

In a nut shell, what I am trying to do is this: [image]

Using the latest version of Leaflet JS, I want to know if its possible to have multiple markers, in a single location, display in a single popup.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

You should pre-process your data beforehand, so that several data points with the same coordinates collapse into the same marker & popup.

In other words: iterate through your data points, and for every data point check if a marker exists in that location. If it does, *add* data to the marker's properties or popup; if it doesn't, create a new marker. The specific algorithm will depend on the nature of your data. You might also want to use a more complex data structure, such as r-trees, if your data set is large.

There's also the quick&dirty option of using [marker clusters](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), disabling spiderifying, then using custom code for the event handlers of the cluster marker. That's pretty much the same algorithm defined above, only that the marker cluster algorithm takes care of locating nearby data points.

Answer (score 1):

I made a similar map, and exactly as described by Ivan, I used [markerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin and on [cluster click](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#user-content-events) action disabled the spiderfy. I then used 'custom code for the event handlers of the cluster marker' to show multiple markers' data in one single outside div.

An example can be found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359347/leaflet-markers-at-same-position-dynamically-display-all-markers-infos-through) .

And there is a tutorial describing exactly what you are looking for [here](https://digital-geography.com/working-with-clusters-in-leaflet-increasing-useability/), but also using [markerCluster js](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).

Hope it can help others people too !